# Angular Flex Layout Pinterest layout

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I using angular material mat card and angular flex layout to display a page of card list. I want to make it like pinterest to have a dynamic height of each card in every row . It that any way to achieve it by using flex layout or other method?

[image]
Below I have a create a stackblitz of my code : [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oksmqs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use this component https://github.com/wynfred/ngx-masonry to achieve the Pinterest layout you want. It support Angular 9 as well.